# Force last label and tick on x-axis

Tags: highcharts

I have a spline graph with date categories on the x-axis. The labels are in steps of 2 so it shows alternate dates. How can I show the last label and tick regardless of the step size ? Example : if the last two labels are 11/6 and 12/6 I want to show 12/6 even if the step size is 2. If the last category is 13/6 then it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the `tickPositioner()` function.

This example uses a simple numeric axis, but should work the same with categories. If you're using an actual `datetime` axis, then the check within the callback function will need to be edited to match your date intervals.

Code example:

```
xAxis: {
  tickPositioner: function() {
    var positions = [],
      ext = this.getExtremes(),
      xMax = Math.round(ext.max),
      xMin = Math.round(ext.min);

    for (var i = xMin; i < xMax; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        positions.push(i);
      }
    }
    positions.push(xMax);
    return positions;
  }
}
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/2cu0ejbg/

Updated fiddle using Monthly categories:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/2cu0ejbg/1/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to have tickInterval of 2 and add an additional tick at the end.  But, if you use a tickInterval of 1, you can display every other label plus the final label using the formatter.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                var label = this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
                if (label % 2 == 1 && !this.isLast) label = '';
                return label;
            }
        },
        tickInterval: 1
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        type: 'line'
    }]

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p665hgo0/